# Why does TypeScript track mutation of function static properties?

Tags: typescript

I always thought that TypeScript does not track object mutations.
For example:

```js
type DescribableObject = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

// error
const obj: DescribableObject = {
  name: 'sdf'
}
obj.age = 2
```

But, it seems that in some circumstances it tracks mutation of function static properties.

```js
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (): boolean;
};

// error
const fn: DescribableFunction = () => true

//fn.description = 'hello';
```

If you uncomment `//fn.description = 'hello';`, the TypeScript error will disappear.

Furthermore, if you hover over `fn` you will see that TS treats `fn` as some kind of `module`.

[image]

What kind of module is the `fn` function?
Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: It’s [property declarations on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions), introduced in TS3.1.  It’s harder to initialize functions “all at once” so they allowed for this.  I’m happy to write up an answer when I get off mobile.

Comment: Related [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370945/how-to-add-static-props-type-for-forwardrefexoticcomponent/69373060#69373060) here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with TypeScript 3.1, you are allowed to [define "expando" properties on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).  This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368) as a fix to [microsoft/TypeScript#15868](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15868).  Apparently there are common patterns where developers add properties to functions in JavaScript, but before this feature there was no idiomatic way to do this in TypeScript.

Right now you can do this:

```
function foo(x: string) { foo.callCount++; return x.length }
foo.callCount = 0;
```

But before TypeScript 3.1 you had to do something like this:

```
function bar(x: string) { bar.callCount++; return x.length }
namespace bar {
  export var callCount = 0;
}
```

or this:

```
const baz = Object.assign(
  (x: string) => { baz.callCount++; return x.length },
  { callCount: 0 }
);
```

or even this:

```
const qux = ((x: string) => { qux.callCount++; return x.length }) as
  { (x: string): number; callCount: number };
qux.callCount = 0;
```

all of which were fairly ugly.

---

While it might be nice to allow expando properties on all objects (like `DescribableObject`) and not just functions, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12416](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12416), it seems that this is not as common or important a pattern to support.  Generally speaking you can use an object literal to add all the properties you want at once (although sometimes dependencies can be difficult to deal with) but you can't do that with a function.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)