# Typescript object with default function typing in React

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wonder how this code written in JavaScript

```
const stuff = useCallback(() => { 
    function first() { 
        return "firstStaff"; 
    }
    function major() { 
        return "majorStaff";
    }
    
    major.first = first;
    
    return major;
})();
```

Can be written with correct types in TypeScript, so it has the right hints for `stuff()` and `stuff.first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in function static property typing you can use this example:

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react'

interface Major {
  (): string
  first: () => string
}

const stuff = useCallback((): Major => {
  function first() {
    return "firstStaff";
  }
  function major() {
    return "majorStaff";
  }

  major.first = first;

  return major;
}, [])();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCBDANrgI2wGMBrOAXzgDMoIQ4ByKdEmRgKA%20ADsZ0o1EujgBZbACtoiDnDgAKAJQAuOKhhReAc1k1gUdaqVwAvAD41G7RwpdiEHusvJq1Uygw58RMvKWrxKShTCwRdamQeYhhgBz0DGGMwuTkWGGQoHjgAImp9dQBlGGxXbIBuXVs5CKiYuJBJaCTdVPR0zJyGoKKS6nLKrjku6AA6PIT3cfUK3TSMrOGoCooAGjgAbQBdRSUyoA)

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties) question/answer if you want to know more about typing static function properties

Answer (score 2):

We can define a type by combining multiple types like this to achieve required

```
type Stuff = { first: () => string } & (() => string);

const stuff: Stuff = useCallback(() => {
...    
})();

  stuff.first();

  stuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

**`useCallback` need an array of dependency as the 2nd argument then it can be self infer**

```
import { useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const stuff = useCallback(() => {
    function first() {
      return "firstStaff";
    }
    function major() {
      return "majorStaff";
    }

    major.first = first;

    return major;
  }, []);

  return (
  ...
  );
}
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit summer-night-zx2bm]