# How to add static props type for ForwardRefExoticComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Modal` FC, I need to add two static methods `show` and `hide` to it. I have no idea how to add the `ModalStaticProps` type for the component. So that I can assign `show` and `hide` to `Modal` directly without using type assertion.

```
import React, { ReactNode, RefAttributes } from 'react';

interface ModalProps {
    title: ReactNode;
}
interface ModalStaticProps {
    show(): void;
    hide(): void;
}
const Modal: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<ModalProps & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> = React.forwardRef<
    HTMLDivElement,
    ModalProps
>(({ title }: ModalProps, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>{title}</div>;
});

// I want to this after add `ModalStaticProps` type
// Modal.show = () => { };
// Modal.hide = () => { };

// Not this
const ModalComponent = Modal as React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<ModalProps & RefAttributes < HTMLDivElement >> & ModalStaticProps
ModalComponent.show = () => { };
ModalComponent.hide = () => { };

function Consumer() {
    return <div onClick={() => ModalComponent.show()} />
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktsgGYCCMMUwARgK4xIDOcAvnJVBCDgByKARhCA3ACgpwAHZsoldEjgBZUigA2ABX5hOOKXBNwYwGFqQAufOhjEy0rrIVIlK9Zq0BlGCnM0PQgDXGNTdgALCAB3AAoASlsANwhgEmlTOEj0pESUtIypFzQIOXZ4DRJtW2R7ADoAMWgYlCgSKgBRAA8IQIBhAUg5JAUAHirtYNCAMnwaOgYWNnYxgAkAFTUAGQARYGTOqxBRmAA+M7gAXjsMesoWto6kSjHwk02d-cPj08x3rzVXT6dhSM5xOJ4cyWVRcWyTYEhdjYUSUBLXS5GLKiGDMKByOBjEgHOCoq44VFcM44aFWLhjAD0xOSZ2cCWkUgZDMB2nqUVi1zgiQxuG40i5PK09RyZEFwqumLFMlK5Uq3kG4DKp0FCLgKE4dTuzSgrXaXV6AyGWvGCOmnDmVFo9CYrA4hLgnz2ByOSBOCjgFzgcwRfgCwCCIKkCI1w1OfOiMTl6IVoq40mjVpGCmluSTIrwaZklGYcgwwDKcEG5WYJygwqxphxeIJRJJZX6WnDAGtyfLLhnNVmYPHYokeAyzsUgA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doable.
See [Properties declarations on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions). It is possible to do, in a natural way, but it might break your ref types.

Hence, I decided just use `Object.assign`

See example:

```js
import React, { ReactNode, RefAttributes, ForwardRefExoticComponent } from 'react';

interface ModalProps {
    title: ReactNode;
}

interface ModalStaticProps {
    show(): void;
    hide(): void;
}

const STATIC_PROPS: ModalStaticProps = {
    show: () => { },
    hide: () => { }
}

const withStaticProps = <T,>(
    forwarded: ForwardRefExoticComponent<ModalProps & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>,
    staticProps: T
) => Object.assign(forwarded, staticProps)


const Modal = React.forwardRef<
    HTMLDivElement,
    ModalProps
>(({ title }: ModalProps, ref) => <div ref={ref}>{title}</div>)

const ModalComponent = withStaticProps(Modal, STATIC_PROPS)

function Consumer() {
    return <div onClick={() => ModalComponent.show()} />
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210929#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktsgGYCCMMUwARgK4xIDO2AYtAO4pQSVAKIAPCDGBoAwhHAQAdkgXwAvnEpQ5cAORQCMHQG4AUCeAqkUSuiRwAsqRQAbAApaw7XCbi%204kmGckAC58dBhiMlNVMws2a1sHJ2cAZRgUSTR3CE9vPzh2AAsIXgAKAEpQgDcIYBJTfMK6pArq2vqTGJM0RXZ4FIAVagGASWkAfVcEAHlXFNDHEhc0jKls3IBePL8iktCKuA2APlw4VUwfPyayffLDk7wYrp6FPrheYBhClcz1ry2ADwDTBHUqXXyUPgCMgkUI8KD8QQicSZWTyJQqAGLFx-OAAMnwNDoDBYbHYAIAEgN7AAZAAiwCqwiCIGUMCORwu%20T6qyyHnYoQGJjuxzg00YACskBgAHQodjsYAAcwUpUhCOhSBI2B5v355TM3V68GxzkOYVl6sRQiQlAB4LgVNpDKZLLZXL8pr%20JlBpTwASCZwWyT%202H0lBFJwBJEZcHDGxw4dURxwAaQqgBAHoY1Ujgaja8Tck0ZAMfAth8vj81vzSqbsINhmNJjM5vnKMwFBhgIo4LJXsxWVADjgHfoYMwoAo4NHY4ppM4pABrBMHUWmkuKNky3ZlcrqTNHTomIA)

See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties) regarding this problem

Comment: I am not sure is: Will TS infer and add the types from `source` to `target` after invoking `Object.assign(target, source)`? I used to think `Object.assign()` will bypass the type check, TS will NOT add infer and add types from source to target. It does, [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGAnA5gU1gXhgbwFAwJjHgFtUAuGAcgEYAmAZioBp9C0oAlEAG1QAoAlDjaFCidAFdEYagAtUPHiCqiYAX1zqA3LlyhIsCCGnBUMLHjEcAqhFSIhIsWIlRpsqvAAmJAJZgqmKamvrg0DCS9ogAyg4Abn5mFjAA8gBGAFaowFAAdPAQEH7IYPwIKOjMMMamqIK4UQ5xiIlmebbRQkA)

Comment: @slideshowp2, sorry, I'm not sure I understood. `Object.assign` intersects two types