# Typescript type throws error while having additonal property

Tags: typescript, types

I am new to typescript. While I was learning signatures, I came across this error. I declared a type with function as shown [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures). It was working fine when I had only the function, later I introduced an additional property to that type, and I don't how to use the type after that.

```
type GreetFunction = {
  (x: string): void;
};
function greeter(fn: GreetFunction) {
 fn("Hello");
}

function printToConsole(a: string) {
  console.log(a);
}

greeter(printToConsole);  //This is working fine ( Converting to js file )
```

But the below code is not converting and giving errors.

```
type GreetFunction = {
  desc: string;
  (x: string): void;
};
function greeter(fn: GreetFunction) {
  fn("Hello");
}

function printToConsole(a: string) {
  console.log(a);
}

greeter(printToConsole); //This is line is giving error
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the `desc` property is supposed to do since it's not used in your code, can you clarify please ?

Comment: @EtienneDldc Yes, my question is how to use that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mutate `printToConsole` and add `desc` property.

```js
type GreetFunction = {
  desc: string;
  (x: string): void;
};
function greeter(fn: GreetFunction) {
  fn("Hello");
}

function printToConsole(a: string) {
  console.log(a);
}
printToConsole.desc = 'df' // <--------------- add desc property

greeter(printToConsole); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gThCwBiBXAdgY2ASwPbpQC8UA3gFBRQAmEAzpgFxR3Bw7oDmA3JVABQAPZq3ZcAlMwBueHNV4BfXgDMM2fIU4IkEOP2Xpm8RCjW4C4snwP8ARAAkIAGyd5b4xeXKqs5wmDFgABU8AGECOjwnCH4AQxE2Dk5LCipMCKiIADpXTjiPcgVyAI5gsIzorNoGYigAcmplOqgAehaoAB4AWh7evv6oWOpqGnpMKAC8SDhQLy0TXX4S9DLw9Ejoj1b2vABrIA)

This is the rare case when TypeScript tracks mutations.
Please see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties)