# Type declaration for function with additional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Anyone know how to define a type for a function that has additional properties e.g.

```js
foo({ name: 'john' })
foo.type
```

I assumed the following would work but TS believes that foo instead returns the function and is not callable itself with the payload argument.

```js
type FuncWithType = {
  (): (payload: { name: string}) => ({ type: string; payload: { name: string }});
  type: string
}
```

Playground with above example and my faulty solution [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYHUCWwAWAVc0C8UA3gFBRQAUAlAFyVgC[…]QgSJFYEUSgGOnhkdCxcSAUoAAZ3BgpScj5BOgByYAhRItcqbIA6RyA](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYHUCWwAWAVc0C8UA3gFBRQAUAlAFyVgC%5B%E2%80%A6%5DQgSJFYEUSgGOnhkdCxcSAUoAAZ3BgpScj5BOgByYAhRItcqbIA6RyA) (edited)

Comment: _"TS believes that foo instead returns the function and is not callable itself with the payload argument"_ - that's exactly what you've defined, `(): T` means it's callable with no parameters and returns `T`. Try https://tsplay.dev/mpvr7w. Also note your playground link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&ssl=7&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYHUCWwAWBRAHsAJwEMAFAgezAGcAeAFQD4oBeKOqAMigG8AoKKDRIMAFGCIgANuSIATAFxQSASkXsu3KOKkyFSqAF8A3LwO9esiEklEC0JOQRVgUAGblyi+MnRY8hUgpqGk1QSEVnAjQEAHNDBhN3cgA6MIheBycXOyo4SRdWJJFNBCIAWwhFAHIAK3JMBCrDZRMgA)

```ts
type FuncWithExtraProps<T> = T & {
  <P>(payload: P): T & { payload: P };
}

declare const foo: FuncWithExtraProps<{ type: string }>;
foo.type
const result = foo({ name: 'john' });
```

and you can even restrict the type of the parameter(s):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&ssl=16&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgFBSgBQIYCcMFsDOUEAHsBHACaECucA1nAPYDucA2gLpQC8UGcITgBoUUAEoR81ADbAefASIB88gBQA6TWGx58ALnQ6CASh4qJU2QG4kSUJFi0AxgHUAlsAAWAUVI40WIxg+Ai+wP6BwUKGINKMGBQqvKqi8MioqGzasfEUBpg5CRwiGVBhEUGEAGRQAN5Q2XEJ+RiFFFAAvqJKojXlGAGVSMY2SBQQTtLY0E6McPhyAGaMjAYwzu5e-YPBCPX2EAYLWG5wAOad0fVweIdQx6cXHUo2y4zqB0iz83JYkjJyXhvVTXW4GADkACtGJ44ODOiMkEA)

```ts
type Fn<
  Params extends unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...params: Params) => Result;

type FuncWithExtraProps<ExtraProps, Payload> = (
  Fn<
    [payload: Payload],
    ExtraProps & { payload: Payload }
  >
  & ExtraProps
);

declare const foo: FuncWithExtraProps<{ type: string }, { name: string }>;
foo.type
const result = foo({ name: 'john' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties) question.

Consider this example:

```js
type FuncWithType = {
    (): (payload: { name: string }) => ({ type: string; payload: { name: string } });
    type: string
}

const foo: FuncWithType = () => {
    return (payload) => ({
        type: 'foo',
        payload
    })
}

foo.type='hello'
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3agkw)

Please keep in mind, that your representation of `FuncWithType` expects function which returns a function.
This syntax `(): (payload: { name: string }) => ({ type: string; payload: { name: string } });`  means that there is a function without arguments `()` which returns another function with `payload` argument.

If you want to declare a type of non curried function you can use this syntax:

```js
type FuncWithType =
    & ((payload: { name: string }) => ({ type: string; payload: { name: string } }))
    & {
        type: string
    }

const foo: FuncWithType = (payload) => ({
    type: 'foo',
    payload
})

foo.type = 'hello'
```