# How can I assign a value to a variable of a callable type?

Tags: typescript

How can I assign a variable of a callable type (type with call signature)?

```
interface CallableType<T> {
  (isSomething: boolean): T
  description: string
}

const fn: CallableType<number> = ?

const result = fn(false)
```

How can I assign a value to `fn` so that it can have a property description and it's callable at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter solution would be to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
// fn is (<T>(x: T) => T) & { description: string }
const fn = Object.assign(<T>(x: T) => x, { description: 'description here' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way but maybe not the best

```
interface CallableType<T> {
  (x: T): T
  description: string
}

let foo = <T>(x: T) => x

const fn = foo as CallableType<string>

fn.description = 'description here'

console.log(fn('some string'))
```

Comment: No need to youse type assertion `as CallableType<string>`. TypeScript track mutation here. Please see [example](https://tsplay.dev/w2anVW) and related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties)