# How to type React's forwardRef with useImperativeHandle in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

Here is a simplified version of a `Tabs` component that exposes a method called `activateTab` through `useImperativeHandle`:

```
type TabsProps<TabName> = {
  tabs: readonly { name: TabName }[];
  children: ReactNode;
};

const TabsComponent = <TabName extends string>(
  props: TabsProps<TabName>,
  ref: Ref<{ activateTab: (tabName: TabName) => void }>
) => {
  const { tabs, children } = props;

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    activateTab: (tabName: TabName) => {}
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <div role="tablist">
        {tabs.map(({ name }) => (
          <button type="button" role="tab" key={name}>
            {name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Tabs = forwardRef(TabsComponent);

// Usage:

const tabs = [{ name: "Tab 1" }, { name: "Tab 2" }] as const;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Tabs tabs={tabs}>
      {...}
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

All is good until this point. Here is a [working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-platform-d9uent).

But, now I want to add a `Tabs.Panel` component so the usage is:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Tabs tabs={tabs}>
      <Tabs.Panel>Content</Tabs.Panel>
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

I tried the following, but TypeScript complains:

```
type PanelProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const Panel = ({ children }: PanelProps) => {
  return <div role="tabpanel">{children}</div>;
};

Tabs.Panel = Panel;
     ~~~~~
       ^
       Property 'Panel' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<TabsProps<string> & RefAttributes<{ activateTab: (tabName: string) => void; }>>'
```

What's the best way to achieve this `Tabs.Panel` API in TypeScript?

[Non-working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-cookies-7pq5tt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Object.assign`:

```js
import React, { forwardRef, ReactNode, Ref, useImperativeHandle, FC } from "react";

type PanelProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const Panel = ({ children }: PanelProps) => {
  return <div role="tabpanel">{children}</div>;
};

type TabsProps<TabName> = {
  tabs: readonly { name: TabName }[];
  children: ReactNode;
};

const TabsComponent = <TabName extends string>(
  props: TabsProps<TabName>,
  ref: Ref<{ activateTab: (tabName: TabName) => void }>
) => {
  const { tabs, children } = props;

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    activateTab: (tabName: TabName) => { }
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <div role="tablist">
        {tabs.map(({ name }) => (
          <button type="button" role="tab" key={name}>
            {name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Tabs = Object.assign(forwardRef(TabsComponent), { Panel });

const tabs = [{ name: "Tab 1" }, { name: "Tab 2" }] as const;

export default function App() {
  return <Tabs tabs={tabs}>
    <Tabs.Panel>Content</Tabs.Panel> // ok
  </Tabs>;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXj3om)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties) you can find more explanation about using [static properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions) on functions

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!!