# TypeScript types for JS objects

Tags: typescript

I am struggling to have VS code suggest the list of keys for the below snippet. Could you please help me to get the keys autopopulate?

```
const myVar : Record<string, string> = {
        key1: 'val1',
        
     }
    myVar.key2 = "val2",
    myVar.key3 = "val3";

     myVar. //doesn't populate the keys
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually specify the keys that are possible in your object. As the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) says, `Record` is not the right type for you:

> Record<Keys, Type>
>
> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

You can do something like this:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
  key3: string;
}

const myVar : MyInterface = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: '',
    key3: '',
 }
 myVar.key2 = "val2":
 myVar.key3 = "val3";
```

Comment: @Garuno - Thank you...If I have too many keys (may be 10-15), is this the only way to have it autopopulate?

Comment: If you want to have autocomplete, you will have to define exactly what keys with what types are allowed/required in the object.

Answer (score 2):

In general, typescript does not track mutations. Except [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties). Apart from that, once you defined explicit type for `myVar`, I mean `Record<...>`, TS will not infer any properties for you, except the case when you use [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) operator.

However, if you want to use explicit type `Record<string, string>` for your `myVar` and want to mutate it, you can consider using [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

```js
const myVar: Record<string, string> = {
  key1: 'val1',

}
myVar.key2 = "val2",
myVar.key3 = "val3";

function mutate<
  Obj extends { [prop: string]: string },
  Key extends string,
  Value extends string
>(obj: Obj, key: Key, value: Value): asserts obj is Obj & Record<Key, Value> {
  Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value })
}

mutate(myVar, 'key1', 'val2')

myVar.key1 // val2
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5RKW)

I strongly recommend you to avoid mutations in typescript. TS does not like it, see [my article](https://catchts.com/mutations)